# Unable to understand the errors I am getting while making a tab bar view controller in swift UIKit

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I was trying to follow a tutorial and make a spotify clone. I am trying to make a tab bar in my app programmatically using the following code. I can't understand the errors I am getting, it is literally the same code used in the tutorial. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c15n.png)

[This is the tutorial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgILL.jpg)

I tried looking up the errors but didn't understand what's going on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you didn't follow the tutorial exactly. The tutorial put everything inside `viewDidLoad`. Also, you should post code as *text*, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome To SOF!

you see the curly brackets `{` and `}` of the function `viewDidLoad` well you need to move your code inside of the brackets

so:

```swift
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //your code should be here
}

//NOT HERE (this is outside the function)
```